# Unable to upload files to my S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently created an AWS free tier account and created an S3 bucket for an experimental project using rails deployed in heroku for production. But I am getting an error telling that something went wrong.

Through my heroku logs, I received this description :-

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'</Message><Region>us-east-2</Region><RequestId>08B714808971C8B8</RequestId><HostId>lLQ+li2yctuI/sTI5KQ74icopSLsLVp8gqGFoP8KZG9wEnX6somkKj22cA8UBmOmDuDJhmljy/o=</HostId></Error>
```

I had put my S3 location to US East (Ohio) instead of the US Standard (I think) while creating the bucket. Is it because of of this?

How I can resolve this error? Is there any way to change the properties of my S3 bucket? If not should I build a fresh bucket and set up a new policy allowing access to that bucket?

Please let me know if there is anything else you need from me regarding this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred authentication mechanism for AWS services, known as Signature Version 4, creates different security credentials for each user, for each service, in each region, for each day.  When a request is signed, it is signed with a signing key specific to that user, date, region, and service.

```
the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'
```

This error means that a request was sent to us-east-2 using the credentials for us-east-1.

The 'region' that is wrong, here, refers to the region of the credentials.

You should be able to [specify the correct region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/index.html#Configuration) in your code, and resolve the issue. For legacy reasons, S3 is a little different than most AWS services, because if you specify the wrong region in your code (or the default region isn't the same as the region of the bucket) then your request is still automatically routed to the correct region... but the credentials don't match.  (Most other services will not route to the correct region automatically, so the request will typically fail in a different way if the region your code is using is incorrect.)

Otherwise, you'll need to create a new bucket in us-east-1, because buckets cannot be moved between regions.

You can keep the same bucket name for the new bucket if you delete the old bucket, first, but there is typically a delay of a few minutes between the time you delete a bucket and the time that the service allows you to reuse the same name to create a new bucket, because the bucket directory is a global resource and it takes some time for directory changes (the bucket deletion) to propagate to all regions.  Before you can delete a bucket, it needs to be empty.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for the answer. I took your idea and then proceeded to find out how to specify the region through carrierwave and it worked

Comment: @NishanthSeshadri If the answer helped fixing the issue then don't forget to mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you nailed the solution to your problem. Just create a bucket in the correct region and use that. If you want it to be called the same thing as your original bucket you'll need to delete it on us-east-2, then create it in us-east-1 as bucket names are globally unique.